# Does spacetime interval at event horizon become light-like for all trajectories?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, spacetime, event-horizon

I have been reading up few papers against the black hole paradigm specifically ECO, and i came across the argument raised by them that at r = 2GM, ds does indeed vanish. Is it correct? Please provide a clarification or point me to some paper regarding this. Thanks.

Comment: the first clue that the $r=2M$ singularity is a coordinate singularity and not a curvature one (this is not a proof, just a hint) is that $ds$ is ultimately proportional to $\sqrt{|g|}$, and this latter quantity does not have a singularity as $r\rightarrow 2M$

Comment: What does ECO mean?

Comment: Eternally Collapsing Object (a black hole mimicker, I'm being skeptic as i did find so many conceptual error in the paper)

Comment: @safesphere [here](https://vixra.org/abs/2001.0501) is my review article, [here](https://www.academia.edu/6015139/BLACK_HOLES_OR_ETERNALLY_COLLAPSING_OBJECTS_A_REVIEW_OF_90_YEARS_OF_MISCONCEPTIONS) is the article on ECO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does spacetime interval at event horizon become light-like for all
>   trajectories?

No. If a geodesic starts time-like, it will stay so. The same goes for light-like and space-like geodesics. But only light-like geodesics can stay at the horizon (if they are directed radially outwards), so the only objects that can keep a constant radial coordinate there are photons. But you will never be as fast or faster than a photon in your vicinity, so if you send a light signal you will never be able to keep up with or overtake it, neither outside nor inside the horizon.

> Please provide a clarification or point me to some paper regarding
>   this.

In [this paper](http://www2.iap.fr/users/charnock/notes/blackholes.pdf#page=7) for example we find the quote *"a timelike geodesic stays timelike and similarly for the spacelike and null geodesics"*, for more information see page 7.

Comment: While you fall through the horizon you can still emitt a photon, just have your flashlight on while you do it. By the way, you brought the same arguments at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/504954/can-a-straight-rod-exist-next-to-or-inside-a-black-hole/504955?noredirect=1#comment1137790_504955 but when I answered you deleted your comments.

Comment: I already told you that the Fidos in Droste coordinates are stationary, which condition can only be fulfilled by photons at the horizon. In Raindrop coordinates where the system is that of a free faller that is not the case, you can transform from one coordinate system to the other with http://cloud.yukterez.net/transform.6.png

Comment: @safesphere - your quote *"The horizon is a coordinate singularity in any coordinates"* tells me that you have never done a coordinate transformation, let alone computed the Kretschmann scalar, otherwise you would know better. Anoyone else who might be interested in the different coordinate systems see http://f.yukterez.net/einstein.equations/files for the Raindrop and Finkelstein coordinates which are without any coordinate singularity at the horizon

Comment: @safesphere - to answer your question *"in the frame of which physical observer would outward photons behave differently from inward?"* - see http://666kb.com/i/dr8y32tpuauqw6a4v.png for the Finkelstein diagram where the red lines are outwards directed photons and the blue lines inward directed ones

Comment: In that case it might be best if we agree to disagree